# Why does my GP offices always have a massive queue?

Tags: two-point-hospital

I have several GP offices throughout the hospital (1 in each building with treatment facilities, sometimes more). Yet no matter how many I add or doctors I train for it, the queue never lets up.

For example, this screenshot is my entrance, with 2 GP offices... the queue pretty much never goes under 20. even though they are high priority rooms with only doctors trained in GP can work in them
[image]

the other GP offices in the hospital are the same story. no other room has a queue like this (some occasionally hit 6 or so, but never this high... or consistently high)

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do your GPs need to confirm the diagnosis before the patient can be treated? Also do you have sufficient diagnosis rooms or are patients hitting up the GP multiple times to hit their diagnosis threshold?

Comment: Confirmation is not enabled. diagnosis rooms are usually right next to GP (you can see one on the left) and never have any queue. When i check the queue most patients are "new", 2 or 3 are revisits. it seems like i just have an endless influx of new patients... but i cant seem to slow it down or manage it to let my GP at least breathe.

Comment: If they're new patients, then you likely need more gp offices. Repeat visitors are because your other diagnosis rooms are insufficient to reach your diagnosis threshold for treatment. You can decrease your repeat volume by building more types of diagnosis rooms, training your nurses in diagnostics, and decreasing the threshold for going to treatment. A patient will only return to the GP if they couldn't meet the threshold after exhausting all other diag rooms.